# How do I write this query without using raw query in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript, bulkupdate

I would like to a bulk update in sequelize. [Unfortunately it seems like sequelize does not support bulk updates](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4501) I am using sequelize-typescript if that helps and using postgresql 14

My query in raw SQL looks like this

```
UPDATE feed_items SET tags = val.tags FROM 
(
    VALUES ('ddab8ce7-afa3-824f-7b65-edfb53a71764'::uuid,ARRAY[]::VARCHAR(255)[]), 
    ('ece9f2fc-2a09-4a95-16ce-07293b0a14d2'::uuid,ARRAY[]::VARCHAR(255)[])
) AS val(id, tags) WHERE feed_items.id = val.id
```

I would like to generate this query from a given array of string and array values. The tags is implemented as a string array in my table.

1. Is there a way to generate the above query without using raw query?
2. Or an SQL injection safe way of generating the above query?

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: @Anatoly postgres

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to use a PostgreSQL function to generate a recordset from an array and pass the array using a named parameter with `bind` option